# RichEdit In RAD C++

Tags: richedit

Hai All I am New to C++ coding and my project needs to following goal.

```
for (int t = 0; t < 100; t++)
{
eArduino->Lines->Add(String("LED") + IntToStr(t)+(","));
}
```

Above is the code for RichEdit in RAD C++ my project need to get Line as follows

LED1,LED2,LED3,LED4,LED5,LED6,LED7,LED8,LED9,LED10
LED11............................................
.............................................,LED100

in my code LED names are comes each new line and how to code get it 10 times and 11 goes to next row. so please help me to get this. `your text`